# Can't update static variable with firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent inside static method

Tags: android, firebase

I am in the need of update a static variable.
I am getting the value from Firebase, but it seems outside the addListenerForSingleValueEvent the static variable is not updated. Where I am wrong?

Flom logcat:

```
02-02 18:16:47.146 8329-8329/xxx E/query_result: null <-- wrong
02-02 18:16:47.675 8329-8329/xxx E/query: Dogee <-- correct
```

Code:

```
class FirebaseUtil {

    public static String nameOfCurrentUser;

// other code . . . 

   public static Author getAuthor() {

        // Is the current user running the app registered?
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) return null;
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        // 20180202 Add the listener on db /users/$currentUID
        mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // Getting the child full_name of the user (mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid()))
                nameOfCurrentUser = (String)dataSnapshot.child("full_name").getValue();
                Log.e("query",nameOfCurrentUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w("DB read error", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                // ...
            }
        });

        if (nameOfCurrentUser == null) {
        Log.e("query_result","null");
```

As you can see once I am out of the method the variable nameOfCurrentUser is != null inside the method, null outside.

Comment: Firebase works in asynchronous mode. hence the null part is logged first.
query_result: null <-- wrong
E/query: Dogee <-- correct

May I know what you like to do with variable nameOfCurrentUser?

Comment: I just need to call Author class which receives uid,nameOfCurrentUser,profilePic) . Data is already on the db and I just need to read that specific entry, not all the db.

Comment: once you get the value, will you update any view (textview) or do you need to pass to some other method?

Comment: need to call Author class which will give me back an Author object      return new Author(nameOfCurrentUser, PicHere, user.getUid());

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729957/android-firebase-getting-null. I do not have option to post answer as this link address the issue, sorry.

Comment: I see, but is that possible that to read just 1 value I have to make all this work? There is no straight way to read just 1 value form 1 key? I already know the full path to read from.

Comment: to read you need not. But if you want to play with the value, then you have to as Firebase is asynchronous. Those listeners help in informing when the data is ready for use. i would suggest try that solution may be for current requirement it may look tedious. It will help you in future.

Comment: If you are using arraylist and adapter then you can try this
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                    doctorsArrayList.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot drDetails : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        doctors = drDetails.getValue(Doctors.class);
                        doctorsArrayList.add(doctors);

                    }              
                    doctorsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

Comment: Thanks, but I do not need to check for data changed. Data is never changed in that value, so I just need a read like .getValue(full_name); is that possible?

Comment: sorry , unfortunately that is not possible. 

Read data once
In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method (which you have already implemented)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks for your help. Anyway it is very time consuming, was expecting something more straight forward as in Firestore to do a simple read.

Comment: if these values are for only for the user who has installed the app and you are storing from the app, then try shared preference. These can save values even after app is close. You will loose them only when you explicitly change or uninstall the app. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html